# Why getting "Destructuring expressions can only have identifier references" when trying to destruct an object?

Tags: javascript, json, object, destructuring

I have the following *object*:

```
const john = {
  family: [
    { firstName: 'david', secondName: 'jana' },
    { firstName: 'eyal', secondName: 'shani ' },
  ],
};
```

I want to get 'david' string in one operation. So i tried the following code:

```
const { family:[0]{firstName}}} = john;
```

But i'm getting the error :

> "Destructuring expressions can only have identifier references"

Can someone tell me in simple words (cause i'm new in the language) what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract a deeply nested value with destructuring, the syntax is nearly identical to when *declaring an object* with those properties. `family:[0]` isn't valid syntax - instead, you need to surround the contents of `family` in array delimiters:

```js
const john = {
  family: [{
      firstName: 'david',
      secondName: 'jana'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'eyal',
      secondName: 'shani '
    },
  ],
};

const { family:[{firstName}]} = john;

console.log(firstName);
```

But I'd highly recommend against using nested destructuring like this. It's so hard to write and read and understand. Better to use plain dot notation at least for the outer accesses, eg

```js
const john = {
  family: [{
      firstName: 'david',
      secondName: 'jana'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'eyal',
      secondName: 'shani '
    },
  ],
};

const { firstName } = john.family[0];
console.log(firstName);
```

Comment: first of all thanks! Secondly why *{ family:[{firstName}]}* goes to the first element in the array and not to the second element?

Comment: Because the `{}` is the first item inside the `[]` brackets. If you did `[, { firstName }]`, you'd be extracting from the second item of the array.